# Configure property name of map based configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

With Spring Boot, can I configure Bar's id, counter, active to be a different configuration name? I know how to do it if it is simple flattened configuration by using @Value(${a.b.c.d}), but for a map based configuration, how can I achieve this?

For example, in below Foo-Bar configuration, how to achieve a setting like:

```
foo.bars.one.bar-counter=10
foo.bars.one.bar-id=1

public class Foo {
  private Map<String, Bar> bars = new HashMap<>();
  public Map<String, Bar> getBars() { .... }
}

public class Bar {
    @Value(${bar-id}) // not work
    private String id;
    @Value(${bar-count})  // not work
    private Integer counter;
}
```

Comment: `@ConfigurationProperties` can inject a complete map, including classes as map values, from YAML. Is that what you want?

Comment: @AndyBrown  I would like to keep the property name of the class to be id. But to use bar-id in the application.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

Okay you gotta use Spring `@ConfigurationProperties` configuration classes, you'll end up with something like this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo")
public class FooProperties {

    private List<BarProperty> foos = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<BarProperty> getFoos() {
        return foos;
    }

    public void setFoos(List<BarProperty> foos) {
        this.foos = foos;
    }

    public static class BarProperty {
        private int barCounter;
        private int barId;

        public int getBarCounter() {
            return barCounter;
        }

        public void setBarCounter(int barCounter) {
            this.barCounter = barCounter;
        }

        public int getBarId() {
            return barId;
        }

        public void setBarId(int barId) {
            this.barId = barId;
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you a `application.properties` configuration file like that

```
foo.foos[0].bar-counter=1
foo.foos[0].bar-id=1
foo.foos[2].bar-counter=2
foo.foos[2].bar-id=2
```

or `application.yml` like that

```
foo:
    foos:
     - bar-counter: 1
       bar-id: 1
     - bar-counter: 2
       bar-id: 2
```

> Don't forget to include in your `pom.xml` this dependency to use Spring Configuration Properties

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. But I mean I don't want to (I don't have the access to) change the Bar class field names (id and counter will still be the property names of the class). I just want the settings in application.yml to use bar-id, and bar-counter.  And also, Bar is a map based, not list based.